# Is there any way to programmatically set the camera focus off an iOS device to infinity?

Tags: ios, camera, focus, infinity

I am creating an app that locks the camera focus for video recording purposes. I want to lock the focus to infinity without having the user manually adjust the focus. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, no. You can set the camera into focus-locked mode, as Artem said; put into autofocus mode (focus, then lock), or continuous autofocus mode, but you can't give the camera a specific distance to focus at.

The best I've been able to come up with (for exposure and white balance control, which are similarly limited) is to have the user point the camera at an appropriate scene (in your case, something far away) and have him/her push a lock button.

Details on the capture device API, such as it is:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: A valid answer? It's the only way I've found to do it. You can set the camera's focus to "locked" or "unlocked", and you can tell it to "focus now, and lock" (for specifics, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can't tell the camera *what* to focus on, only *when* to focus. So the only way I can think of to lock focus to infinity is to have the user aim the camera's focus point at something very far away, and then lock it. If you can find a better way, please let us know!

Comment: Another issue: with exposure and white balance, at least, the state of the lock is remembered across invocations of the app, but the locked value isn't. If my app resign active state and then becomes active again, the camera locks whatever value it currently sees, *not* the value it previously had: the *value* is lost even if the *state* is remembered. If focus behaves the same way, then an app that depends on focus-lock should turn it off when backgrounding to avoid an invalid value (I turn off camera locks in my applicationWillResignActive: handler, which seems to cover all the cases).

Answer (score 5):

That is the way to disable focus, it locks it for all the time:

```
// Find a suitable capture device
    AVCaptureDevice *cameraDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // SETUP FOCUS MODE
    if ([cameraDevice lockForConfiguration:nil]) {

        [cameraDevice setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked];

        [cameraDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"error while configuring focusMode");
    }
```

What do you mean "lock the focus to infinity"?

Comment: Lock the focus infinity = lock focus to farthest point possible

Comment: it locks at specific distance, so every time you start up it locks for different distance (not the farthest), so it's not a correct answer

Answer (score 4):

AVCaptureDevice has function setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:completionHandler:

You can use it to set 1.0 in order to achieve "infinity" distance

```
    func focusTo(value : Float) {
      if let device = captureDevice {
      if(device.lockForConfiguration(nil)) {
         device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(value, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
            //
        })
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
      }
    }
```

Update:
According to Apple documentation 1.0 does not represent focus at infinity.

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624643-lensposition)
The range of possible positions is 0.0 to 1.0, with 0.0 being the shortest distance at which the lens can focus and 1.0 the furthest. Note that 1.0 does not represent focus at infinity. The default value is 1.0.

For me it works

Comment: This is the answer but with low votes because it's a new feature.  Thanks!  Very helpful.

Comment: This causes an exception. checking 'lockingFocusWithCustomLensPositionSupported' never returns true no matter the device. What's missing here?

Comment: @kanso Do you check this boolean for back camera?